# iMac developing Bluetooth 4.0 application with external dongle

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have a Late 2009 iMac which doesn't support Bluetooth 4.0 and an USB Bluetooth 4.0 dongle (CSR).

I need to write an OSX application which transfers data with a Bluetooth 4.0 device.

If I plug the dongle, the CBCentralManager returns the state CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported since OSX has loaded the driver for the internal Bluetooth device.

If I issue the following command:

sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="always"

the OSX loads the driver for the dongle, the CBCentralManager recognize the device but unfortunately both wireless keyboard and magic mouse stop working. Presumably because they use a previous version of Bluetooth.

Is there any way to have both internal Bluetooth and external dongle working together ?

Aside from the development, which I can manage with USB keyboard and mouse, this issue prevents older iMacs to use my app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...unfortunately both wireless keyboard and magic mouse stop working. Presumably because they use a previous version of Bluetooth.

This is not true. The iMac takes some time to recognize that it has not keyboard and mouse configured. After waiting some time, the iMac asks for pairing keyboard and everything work correctly with the external dongle.